# Best Solution to Create a change History for several SQL Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

*I've searched a long time and don't found an solution here yet. Also this question is a little bit subjectiv. But i really need a good solution for this task.*

I have a table with Volumes, Security and much more informations.
This data are daily changed.
Now i need to **keep this changes in a history**.

What is the best Solution to do this?
Making a Second table with the same Structure and just insert the "old" data into this table?
Or just making an additional parameter with Status?

Making this server side with triggers?
Or programmatically with a LINQ procedure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We chose separate tables as it will keep your primary table lean and faster.  We also opted for triggers, reasoning that if you ever change the entry mechanism, you wouldn't want to have to rewrite your auditing.  Also it can capture accidental DBA side changes.

Since update is effectively a delete and then an insert, you can achieve what has been suggested with a single trigger- this is what we did.

- Create a table exactly matching your existing table, but with some added columns:
  AUDIT_GUID VARCHAR(40),
  AUDIT_TIMESTAMP DATETIME,
  AUDIT_ACTION VARCHAR(20)
- Create an "AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE" Trigger using the following general pattern (simply add more columns where necessary).

  ```
  CREATE TRIGGER CustomerAudit ON Customer 
  AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE AS 
  BEGIN 
      IF (TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()>1) RETURN

      DECLARE @Time DateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      DECLARE @Audit_GUID varchar(100) = NEWID()  

      INSERT INTO Customer_History (FirstName, LastName, Audit_Date, Audit_Action, Audit_GUID)
      SELECT 
          FirstName, LastName, @Time, 'Delete', @Audit_GUID
      FROM 
          Deleted

      INSERT INTO Customer_History 
  (FirstName, LastName, Audit_Date, Audit_Action, Audit_GUID) 
      SELECT 
          FirstName, LastName, @Time, 'Insert', @Audit_GUID 
      FROM 
          Inserted 
  END
  ```

If you want to find updates, they will be rows in the history table that have a delete & update with the same Audit_GUID value. The timestamp also allows you to check changes made at a certain time, and we've also added a currentuser to find the person to blame if necessary!

Comment: (If anyone can suggest how I can get StackOverflow to format this code properly, please let me know)

Comment: @Runonthespot: Code following a bullet needs 8 leading spaces to format right. I also added a space after commas in the column lists, which seems to help "unwrap" long lines.

Comment: PS @SwissGuy, the "Inserted" and "Deleted" special tables that appear in these types of triggers are very useful for many similar things.

Comment: Hey Runonthespot, thanks for your answer. The timestamp and the action like you suggested is very usefull. But why you create the GUID? can i not just take the Primarykey from the original source? What would be the advantage of this generated GUID?

Comment: The GUID gives you a way of working out what was an update: Consider a situation where you have multiple changes to the same row on the same day.  You can't use primary key, as it appears multiple times in the history. You could look for DELETE/INSERT with the same timestamp, but that might not work 100%. GUID (or any sort of unique number) just means you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: e.g. in the example above, `SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Customer_History GROUP BY Audit_GUID HAVING COUNT(1) = 2` will show you all the updates.

Comment: This approach is valid in some situations. But how to pass username that did business operation (not database connection user). I mean username from some existing table Account that deleted or updated records

Comment: @eldar You need some way of tying an action with who did it and we typically just use SUSER_SNAME.  In our case, security is granted via groups, but this still identifies the login of the user in question.  How would you normally populate "username" in your scenario?

Comment: @Runonthespot We have asp.net mvc application with custom membership provider which authenticate users by given username and password (forms authentication). User information keeps in Account table

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for a `ON DELETE`/`ON UPDATE` trigger that stores deleted or modified rows to a second table.

This way you

- can keep up referential integrity
- can build sensible unique keys in your "live data" table
- don't have to remember adding `WHERE IsDeleted = 'N'` (or the like) with every query you make
- have automatic historization with your data even if you modify it directly on the database

This keeps usability and performance up with your live data. For historic data you'd have to go to your history tables, which in my experience can be cumbersome if the queries are complex and you want to mix live and historic data into one result. Depends on your use case if that kind of usage is a likely scenario.

Comment: You could create a view using `UNION ALL` to combine live and historical data.

Comment: Hey Tomalak.Thanks alot for your answer. This really helped me alot for my next steps

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to create a separate table to track the history along with required fields and date, so that you can query this table as and when required. You can use triggers to log.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create an historical table (suffix _HIST) with all data.  You need three triggers to store UPDATES, DELETIONS and INSERTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't build what you can't buy off the shelf. Google for database auditing software, there's lots out there.